# Emacs/Common Lisp: Quote variable's value

Tags: emacs, lisp

I need the quoted value of a variable.

For example, let's say we have the variables `qwe` and `asd`:

```
(setq qwe '(1 2 3)) ;; qwe is set to (1 2 3)
(setq asd ''(1 2 3)) ;; asd is set to '(1 2 3)
```

My question is: how do I achieve the same value for `asd` by using `qwe`?

I did it this way:

```
(setq asd `(quote ,qwe))
;; Now asd is '(1 2 3)
```

But it looks ugly and bad to me. I'll be surprised if there isn't a better way.

Comment: FWIW the code you've written does precisely what you want, and looks neither ugly nor bad to me. Quite to the contrary, it *very clearly* reads as quoting the evaluated value of `qwe`. What is it that you don't like about it?

Comment: @phils, well, I always try to escape quasiquotes as they appear to be harder to read. I like what Vatine proposed: `(list 'quote qwe)`, which, by me, looks better and is more understandable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for

```
(setq asd `',qwe)
```

which is, in fact, [equivalent](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/02_dc.htm) to

```
(setq asd `(quote ,qwe))
```

Comment: Or indeed `(setq asd (list 'quote qwe))`.

Comment: Thank you, Vatine, your answer is what I was looking for! :)